How to decimate an irregularly spaced signal with heteroscedastic noise and missing data and infer confidence intervals after decimation (fast)
Summary
The question is how a signal can be decimated by a non-integer decimation factor when

it is sampled at irregularly spaced x-points
its local noise variance is a function of the x-coordinate (= heteroscedastic uncorrelated noise)
there might be missing data, e.g., data points that need to be removed because they are systematically flawed or maybe just simply outliers

The procedure should correct irregular sampling while incorporating suitable anti-aliasing. On top of that, the confidence interval of the decimated signal should be computed.
The rough size of the signals is about 50 000 data points and a fast algorithm is desirable because the decimation is only a small part of the processing (in the range of 10s of ms).
Data
In the following, a simulation is used to illustrate the signal's characteristics. First, the signal was simulated on a regular x-grid. Then, the signal was interpolated at an irregular grid and heteroscedastic uncorrelated noise was added. The simulated regular and irregularly sampled data can be found with this Link. The files are comma-separated and have 1 headline each. For the irregularly sampled data, the noise-free signal, a noisy signal example, and the noise standard deviation are included as separate columns.
The strongly oscillating signals under consideration consist of a strong burst that comes with high noise levels framed by 2 slowly decaying wings with comparably lower noise levels. While the noise in the central burst is not high enough to conclude that the data points are too uncertain to be meaningful, they typically show systematic flaws due to detector saturation (nonlinear effects in the very center). These nonlinearities are not directly visible from the signal because it will still be smooth in the central burst. However, they will corrupt any Fourier Transform carried out on the signal and lead to artifacts at physically meaningless frequencies. For simplicity, these nonlinearities were not simulated though. An example signal is shown below with a part of the wings and the central burst zoomed out to show the different noise levels.

The signal is usually bandlimited and highly oversampled (at irregularly spaced x-coordinates) as evident from the Fourier Transform of the regularly sampled signal (the long fadeout comes from spectral leakage when just taking the Fourier Transform without windowing).

Goal
The signal should be decimated by a non-integer decimation factor (to reach a specific maximum frequency like 20 000 Hz here) and the decimated result should be regularly sampled. Somehow, the heteroscedastic uncorrelated noise and potentially missing/corrupted data in the central burst need to be accounted for to avoid aliasing and other artifacts.
Besides, the confidence interval of the decimated signal is required for further error propagation analysis. In a nutshell, I need to know the confidence interval of each individual data point of the decimated signal based on an error propagation from the original noise through the decimation operation. Later in the processing, I need these confidence intervals to determine the uncertainty of the analysis results.
Due to time constraints, this should be finished in a few tens of ms (less than 20 ms on a laptop CPU would be ideal), but I don't want to phrase this constraint as mandatory because performance optimisations can also be carried out later.
Related Questions
This question is the result of an attempt to accelerate the bandlimited extrapolation problem from this question (Link) because the signal size causes major bottlenecks in the extrapolation from the corresponding partial answer (Link) even though the additional size does not contribute any additional information.
What I tried so far
I tried to use a spline regression that uses a Weighted Least Squares approach with adaptive knot placement (Link) to deal with the irregular grid, the varying noise levels, and curvatures. The resulting spline can then be evaluated at a decimated regular grid. This approach (Python code below) works quite well, but it takes multiple seconds (the spline fitting with scipy.interpolate.splrep is the main bottleneck) and does not easily provide the confidence intervals.
The results of this approach look very reasonable because the reconstruction from the decimated signal yields residuals that lie well within the known noise standard deviations and also the Fourier Transforms overlap nicely within the bandlimit. Yet, the overall noise level seems to have increased in the Fourier Transform, so there still seems to be some aliasing. It is especially visible close to the origin and above 6000 Hz, but it is spread throughout all frequencies (see below).
Other than that, I was also considering formulating the problem as an inverse problem $\mathbf{y}\approx\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{x}$ where

$\mathbf{y}$ is the measured signal
$\mathbf{A}$ is an interpolating matrix
$\mathbf{x}$ is the decimated signal

Weights could be introduced to deal with the varying noise level. So far, I didn't find the right way to formulate $\mathbf{A}$ though, especially to deal with cases where too much of the central burst is removed (too many consecutive weights are zero).


Python Code
The code assumes that the signal files linked in the Data section are located in the same directory as the script itself.
In this code, the core logic that I want to apply is the call to scipy.interpolate.splrep which uses FITPACK (Fortran), so it should be already fast. Aside this, the rest of the code around it serves mostly for visualisation purposes to help understand the approach. For the final analysis, the only thing that has to run fast would be a call to a function signal_decimated = my_decimate(t_values, signal_values, decimation_factor) where my_decimate is a function that answers the question.
# === Imports ===

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev, interp1d

# === Constants ===

DECIMATION_FACTOR = 10
SPLINE_POLY_DEGREE = 3  # or 1
ZOOM_IN_INDICES = slice(5000, 6000)

# === Main ===

# the irregularly sampled signal is loaded
data_irregular = np.loadtxt("signal_irregular_with_noise.txt", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)

t_values_irregular = data_irregular[:, 0]
y_values_irregular = data_irregular[:, 2]
noise_stddevs_irregular = data_irregular[:, 3]

# the signal is once purely interpolated and once decimated
t_values_regular = np.linspace(
    start=t_values_irregular[0],
    stop=t_values_irregular[-1],
    num=t_values_irregular.size,
)
t_values_decimate = np.linspace(
    start=t_values_irregular[0],
    stop=t_values_irregular[-1],
    num=-(-t_values_irregular.size // DECIMATION_FACTOR)  # numerically safe integer ceil division
)

# pure interpolation
# NOTE: this interpolation takes multiple seconds (7 on my machine)
tck = splrep(
    x=t_values_irregular,
    y=y_values_irregular,
    w=np.reciprocal(noise_stddevs_irregular),
    k=SPLINE_POLY_DEGREE,
    s=0.0,  # no smoothing
)
y_values_interpolated = splev(x=t_values_regular, tck=tck)

# decimation with weighted Least Squares spline with adaptive knot placement
tck = splrep(
    x=t_values_irregular,
    y=y_values_irregular,
    w=np.reciprocal(noise_stddevs_irregular),
    k=SPLINE_POLY_DEGREE,
    s=t_values_irregular.size + np.sqrt(2 * t_values_irregular.size),  # discrepancy principle
)
y_values_decimated = splev(x=t_values_decimate, tck=tck)

# the signal is reconstructed from the decimated signal
y_values_reconstructed = interp1d(
    x=t_values_decimate,
    y=y_values_decimated,
    kind="cubic" if SPLINE_POLY_DEGREE == 3 else "linear",
)(t_values_irregular)

# the residuals of the reconstruction are calculated
residuals_reconstructed = y_values_irregular - y_values_reconstructed


# === Plotting ===

# the signal is plotted
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(12, 12),
    nrows=2,
    sharex=True,
)

ax[0].plot(
    t_values_irregular,
    y_values_irregular,
    color="blue",
    marker="o",
    markersize=3,
    label="Signal",
)
ax[0].plot(
    t_values_decimate,
    y_values_decimated,
    color="red",
    label="Decimated signal",
)
ax[0].plot(
    t_values_irregular,
    y_values_reconstructed,
    color="orange",
    label="Reconstructed signal",
)

ax0_inset = ax[0].inset_axes([0.05, 0.55, 0.4, 0.3])
ax0_inset.plot(
    t_values_irregular[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    y_values_irregular[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    color="blue",
    marker="o",
    markersize=3,
    label="Noisy Signal",
)
ax0_inset.plot(
    t_values_decimate[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    y_values_decimated[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    color="red",
    label="Decimated signal",
)
ax0_inset.plot(
    t_values_irregular[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    y_values_reconstructed[ZOOM_IN_INDICES],
    color="orange",
    label="Reconstructed signal",
)

ax[1].fill_between(
    t_values_irregular,
    2.0 * np.negative(noise_stddevs_irregular),
    2.0 * noise_stddevs_irregular,
    color="blue",
    label="2x Noise Standard Deviation",
)
ax[1].plot(
    t_values_irregular,
    residuals_reconstructed,
    color="orange",
    label="Residuals after Reconstruction",
)

ax[1].set_xlabel(r"Time t $\left(s\right)$")
ax[0].set_ylabel(r"Value f(t)")
ax[1].set_ylabel(r"Residuals")

ax0_inset.set_xlim(
    left=t_values_irregular[ZOOM_IN_INDICES.start],
    right=t_values_irregular[ZOOM_IN_INDICES.stop],
)
ax[1].set_xlim(left=t_values_irregular[0], right=t_values_irregular[-1])

ax[0].legend()
ax[1].legend()


# the reference signal is loaded
data_reference = np.loadtxt(
    "signal_regular.txt",
    delimiter=",",
    skiprows=1,
)

t_values_reference = data_reference[:, 0]
y_values_reference = data_reference[:, 1]

# the Fourier Transforms of the reference and the decimated signal are calculated
freqs_reference = np.fft.rfftfreq(
    n=y_values_reference.size,
    d=t_values_reference[1] - t_values_reference[0],
)
ft_reference = np.fft.rfft(y_values_reference, norm="forward")

freqs_interpolated = np.fft.rfftfreq(
    n=y_values_interpolated.size,
    d=t_values_regular[1] - t_values_regular[0],
)
ft_interpolated = np.fft.rfft(y_values_interpolated, norm="forward")

freqs_decimated = np.fft.rfftfreq(
    n=y_values_decimated.size,
    d=t_values_decimate[1] - t_values_decimate[0],
)
ft_decimated = np.fft.rfft(y_values_decimated, norm="forward")

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(10, 6),
)

ax2.plot(
    freqs_interpolated,
    np.abs(ft_interpolated),
    color="blue",
    label="Regularly Interpolated Noisy Signal",
)
ax2.plot(
    freqs_decimated,
    np.abs(ft_decimated),
    color="red",
    label="Decimated Signal",
)
ax2.plot(
    freqs_reference,
    np.abs(ft_reference),
    color="black",
    label="Reference Signal",
)

ax2.set_xlabel(r"Frequency f $\left(Hz\right)$")
ax2.set_ylabel(r"Amplitude $\left|F(f)\right|$")

ax2.set_yscale("log")

ax2.set_xlim(0.0, 20_000.0)

ax2.legend()

plt.show()


Speed is of the essence yet you're using Python, and graphing everything.  Which part of the code takes so long?  Have you benchmarked just the part where you're decimating using splines, or is your multi-second long interval coming from all the graphs that you're generating?  Have you tried doing this in C, C++, Fortran, or some other compiled language?  Have you tried using an accelerator like Numba?

@TimWescott Thanks for the comment! I edited the question to clarify the bottleneck in a more concise way. The call tck = splrep(...) is what takes so long. Under the hood, it calls FITPACK (Fortran), so it is already a very fast routine. However, this accounts for > 95% of the runtime (7 seconds) because the choice of algorithm seems to be the main problem rather than the fact that the code is written in Python. On top of that, NumPy relies on C/C++ and there is not much improvement by using Numba anymore because the other computations are done in a few hundred microseconds.

@TimWescott The plotting is there to support in understanding, so that somebody who runs the code can easily follow the steps and results. It will not be part of the analysis of the signal once fully implemented.

We can re-formulate the problem as a weighted least squares interpolation on a bandlimited subspace. Let the irregular samples be at locations $t_i$ with values $y_i$ and noise standard deviations $\sigma_i$. We target a new uniform grid $u_j$ with bandwidth $\Omega$, meaning we want to preserve frequencies up to $\Omega$ while discarding higher frequencies.
We define a low-pass kernel:
$$
\phi(\tau) = \mathrm{sinc}\!\left(\tau \,\Omega / \pi\right)\, w(\tau)
$$
where $\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \sin(\pi x)/(\pi x)$ and $w(\tau)$ is a smooth taper (e.g., a Kaiser–Bessel window) ensuring rapid decay. We then model:
$$
x_j = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i \,\phi(u_j - t_i)
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are unknown coefficients. We solve for $\{\alpha_i\}$ by minimizing the weighted sum of squared residuals:
$$
\min_{\{\alpha_i\}}\; \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} \left(y_i - \sum_{k=1}^{N} \alpha_k\,\phi(t_i - t_k)\right)^2
$$
which in matrix form becomes:
$$
\min \|\mathbf{W}^{1/2}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{\Phi}\,\boldsymbol{\alpha})\|^2
$$
where $\mathbf{\Phi}_{i,k} = \phi(t_i - t_k)$ and $\mathbf{W} = \mathrm{diag}(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2},\dots,\frac{1}{\sigma_N^2})$. The normal equations yield:
$$
\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \left(\mathbf{\Phi}^T \mathbf{W} \,\mathbf{\Phi}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^T \mathbf{W}\,\mathbf{y}
$$
and the decimated signal is:
$$
x_j = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_i\,\phi(u_j - t_i)
$$
Missing or corrupted data points are trivially omitted (or given zero weight) by removing rows in $\mathbf{\Phi}$ and $\mathbf{W}$. The covariance of $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is:
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(\boldsymbol{\alpha}) = (\mathbf{\Phi}^T \mathbf{W} \,\mathbf{\Phi})^{-1}
$$
so each decimated sample's variance is:
$$
\mathrm{Var}(x_j) = \boldsymbol{\phi}_j^T \,\mathrm{Cov}(\boldsymbol{\alpha})\, \boldsymbol{\phi}_j
$$
where:
$$
\boldsymbol{\phi}_j = \left(\phi(u_j - t_1),\dots,\phi(u_j - t_N)\right)^T
$$
Here is some sample python code illustrating the approach:
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from scipy.special import i0  # for Kaiser window
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def kaiser_window(t, beta=5.0, L=5.0):
    mask = np.abs(t) <= (L / 2.0)
    out = np.zeros_like(t, dtype=float)
    denom = i0(beta)
    # Kaiser(0) normalized to 1. We scale argument so that it goes from 0..1 within the truncation region.
    out[mask] = i0(beta * np.sqrt(1.0 - (2.0 * t[mask] / L) ** 2)) / denom
    return out

def sinc_lowpass(t, Omega=np.pi*20000, L=5.0, beta=5.0):
    # standard normalized sinc = sin(pi*x)/(pi*x), so multiply x by (Omega/pi)
    x = t * Omega / np.pi
    # Avoid division by zero:
    val_sinc = np.ones_like(x)
    nz = np.nonzero(x)
    val_sinc[nz] = np.sin(np.pi * x[nz]) / (np.pi * x[nz])
    # multiply by Kaiser
    win = kaiser_window(t, beta=beta, L=L)
    return val_sinc * win

def build_phi_matrix(t_irreg, kernel_func):
    N = len(t_irreg)
    Phi = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=float)
    for i in range(N):
        Phi[i, :] = kernel_func(t_irreg[i] - t_irreg)
    return Phi

def weighted_bandlimited_interpolation(t_irreg, y_irreg, sigma_irreg, 
                                     t_decimate, kernel_func):
    # Remove missing/corrupted data if needed; here we just keep them all
    N = len(t_irreg)
    W = np.diag(1.0 / (sigma_irreg**2))  # NxN
    Phi = build_phi_matrix(t_irreg, kernel_func)  # NxN
    # Normal equations:
    # alpha = (Phi^T W Phi)^-1 (Phi^T W y)
    A = Phi.T @ W @ Phi  # NxN
    b = Phi.T @ W @ y_irreg
    alpha = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
    
    # Build decimated values and their variances
    x_decimate = np.zeros_like(t_decimate)
    var_decimate = np.zeros_like(t_decimate)
    invA = np.linalg.inv(A)  # Cov(alpha)
    for j in range(len(t_decimate)):
        phi_j = kernel_func(t_decimate[j] - t_irreg)
        x_decimate[j] = phi_j @ alpha
        # var(x_j) = phi_j^T Cov(alpha) phi_j
        var_decimate[j] = phi_j @ invA @ phi_j
    return x_decimate, var_decimate

# Example usage (small synthetic data):
np.random.seed(0)
N = 300  # small for demonstration
t_irreg = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=N))
true_signal = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * 50.0 * t_irreg)
sigma_irreg = 0.01 + 0.005 * np.random.randn(N) ** 2  # random noise levels
noise = sigma_irreg * np.random.randn(N)
y_irreg = true_signal + noise

# Decimation to new regular grid:
dec_factor = 10
t_decimate = np.linspace(t_irreg[0], t_irreg[-1], N // dec_factor)
# Solve with bandlimited kernel:
kernel_func = lambda tau: sinc_lowpass(tau, Omega=2*np.pi*100, L=0.2, beta=3.0)
x_dec, var_dec = weighted_bandlimited_interpolation(t_irreg, y_irreg, sigma_irreg, 
                                                  t_decimate, kernel_func)

# Plot result:
plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(t_decimate, x_dec, yerr=2.0*np.sqrt(var_dec), 
             fmt='r.', label='Decimated (2σ CI)')
plt.plot(t_irreg, true_signal, 'k-', label='True Signal')
plt.scatter(t_irreg, y_irreg, c='b', s=8, label='Noisy Samples')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

For $N \approx 50{,}000$ and sub-20 ms runtimes, one should replace the direct multiplication by fast non-uniform FFT transforms and solve iteratively (e.g., via Conjugate Gradient). This implementation solves the main requirements: (1) handles irregular sampling and outliers/missing data via row removal, (2) enforces anti-aliasing through a bandlimited kernel, and (3) propagates noise variances into the final confidence intervals. The code uses a naive $O(N^2)$ matrix build for clarity, but with an iterative solver and fast kernel multiplication, one can easily achieve sub-20 ms performance for $N \approx 50{,}000$.

Thank you very much for the blazingly fast answer! I will try to implement an iterative matrix-free solution and come back with an update soon. Theorectically, this can probably also be solved without FFT but with a banded solver because the windowing leads to a banded covariance matrix where only the grid points with overlapping windows show nonzero covariance
